# HTML lable внутри div выдает ошибку валидации

Tags: html, валидация

Знаю, что внутрь lable нельзя вставлять блочные элементы, например div, но почему если, наоборот:

```
<div><lable></lable></div>
```

Валидатор тоже выдает ошибку: **Error: Element lable not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)**

Валидатор: https://validator.w3.org

Comment: Возможно просто опечатка, label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас опечатка, правильно писать `<label>`.
Автор - [Pavel Grishaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/347472/pavel-grishaev)

Comment: Ай да авторство )))